# Button inside my Fragment is not recognised

Tags: java, android, button, fragment

I want to test if the button works on my application.
    They are placed inside my first fragment. When I click "All" Button it does not respond at all. My main goal is to load fragment,but in this case I put System.out.println just to test if my button is going to work,but it obviously is not working.

I have tried to make new project and it works,but only inside Main Activity,I want this inside me Exercises_Tab fragment.

I do not see any error logs at all..

```
    public class Exercises_Tab extends Fragment {

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View Exercises = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container,false);

                Button allbtn = (Button) Exercises.findViewById(R.id.all_button);

            allbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("Test");
                }
            });
                    return Exercises;
                }
            }
```

And my XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Linear_Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text= " Muscles "
                android:background="#000000"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>






            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewhorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:paddingVertical="-20dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">




                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:text="All"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:id="@+id/all_button"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:id="@+id/second_button"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:textColor="#696969" />
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="Button 1"
                        android:background="#fafafa"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_margin="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>




    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Frame_Layout"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Linear_Layout"


        >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @peco Your answer is equivalent to what they already have, anyway. Ultimately, it doesn't matter in which method you call `findViewById()` on the inflated `View`. The `Button` is created during the inflation, not after `onCreateView()` returns.

Comment: @Mike.M so it doesn't matter when you set onClickListener in onViewCreate or onViewCreated because the layout is created with inflater.inflate and in this example that s in first line of onCreateView method right?

Comment: @peco Right. The `View` objects are actually created right at the `inflate()` call, so you can modify them however you want any time after that. Those exact same objects will later be passed into `onViewCreated()`, but nothing will have changed on them since `onCreateView()`, so you could do all of your setup in `onCreateView()`, if you really want. The `onViewCreated()` method just makes it easier to keep your code neat and tidy, basically. (Btw, you didn't quite get my username exact, so I didn't get notified. I wasn't ignoring you, or anything.)

Comment: @MikeM.  I have tried similar action in my new acitivity and ot works pretty fine, but the buttons, view and inflater is declared inside the MainActivity, but in real project, they are inside Fragment Class, not Main activity,what could I do to fix my problem since buttons are not working and all. And btw, thanks for edit.

Comment: It's hard to say. The `Fragment` code is fine, and it seems like that's the right layout, 'cause otherwise it'd probably crash. Do you get any visual feedback when you click the `Button`? That is, does it look like it's getting clicked? Also, are you sure you're not just missing that log print? Have you tried something a little more noticeable, like a `Toast`? And, how are you loading that `Fragment`, exactly? Is it in a `<fragment>` element in the `Activity`'s layout? Or are you doing a transaction in code? Are you sure that what you see on-screen is really `Exercises_Tab`?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes,I receive visual information from my emulator, but nothing happens inside log,there i no output information,This fragment where buttons are places I load through PlaceHolder class.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perform your entire code inside this function for fragment as it already has a reference to your xml view.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   Button allbtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.all_button);
   allbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("Test");
           }
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can implement the click listener like

```
public class Exercises_Tab extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button allbtn ;

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState) {
        View Exercises = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container,false);
        allbtn = (Button) Exercises.findViewById(R.id.all_button);
        allbtn .setOnClickListener(this);
        return Exercises ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
    }
}
```

I prefer this because it makes your code more readable.